# Unable to login to our server using Winscp/FileZilla

Tags: filezilla, winscp

When we tried to login to our server using WinSCP/FileZilla, we got below error:

```
Error:         FATAL ERROR: Remote side sent disconnect message; Error: type 11 (by application): Error:         "Unsupported protocol sequence";  Error:         Could not connect to server Earlier we are able to connect to it, from past few days we got this error.
```

Any suggestions please.

Thanks

Venkat